# how to i convert vertical output of for loop into one list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have output

```
3
3
4
4
5
6
6
```

and i would like to have it in list

```
[3,4,4,5,6,]
```

this is my code

```
grading_journal= {
'pup1': {   
            'name' : 'Adam',
            'surname' : 'Smith',
            'grade': [3,3,4,4]
},
'pup2': {
            'name' : 'Jenny',
            'surname3' : 'Lopez',
            'grade' : [5,6,5]   
},
'pup3': {
            'name' : '',
            'surname' : '',
            'grade' : []    
},
}

for pup in grading_journal.values():
    myList = [] 
    for element in pup['grade']:
        print(element)
```

How to convert this vertical output as a resault of for loop into one horisontal list like that [3,4,4,5,6,] ?

Comment: `myList.extend(pup['grade'])` and get rid of the 2nd inner loop

Comment: and also move the `myList = []` above the `for pup ..` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add each element to your defined list and make sure to define `myList` before the loop to prevent overwriting it on each iteration:

```
myList = []
for pup in grading_journal.values(): 
    for element in pup['grade']:
        myList += [element]
```

Then if you `print(mylist)` you should see `[3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5]`

Comment: i see something like this ```[3]
[3, 3]
[3, 3, 4]
[3, 3, 4, 4]
[3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
[3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5]```

Comment: pls share your full revised code

Comment: ah I think you are printing during each iteration of the loop. try pulling out your print statement to after the loop.

Comment: that is correct, you have right, thx

Comment: thx pls accept answer if it worked out

Answer (score -1):

check this

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

print(str(my_list)) # [1, 2, 3]

# or

elements = ""
for el in my_list:
    elements += str(el) + ","

print(f"[{elements}]") # [1,2,3,]
```